# How to extract the number of hydrogens from a chemical formula (i.e. from C18H36P1 to get the 36) using Pandas

Tags: python, chemistry

I would like to be able to make a new column in a pandas dataframe that comprises the number of hydrogens from a chemical formula. Getting the number hydrogens from this chemical formula C18H36P1S1, would give 36. The Chemical formulas are general so you can't just feed the exact chemical formula, there are thousands of them in a column.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

REGEX = re.compile(r'H(?P<hydrogens>\d+)')
REGEX.search('C18H36P1S1').group('hydrogens')
```

returns:

`'36'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'formula':['C18H36P1S1']})
df['No Hydrogens'] = df['formula'].str.extract('.*H(\d+)[A-Za-z].*')


    formula     No Hydrogens
0   C18H36P1S1  36
```

Comment: It gives the answer in a new column.

Comment: What if you wanted to feed in arbitrary formulas for thousands of rows?

Comment: This implementation works for an arbitrary number of rows, not just 1

Comment: how is it general if you feed in 'formula':['C18H36P1S1']? Wouldn't you need to write something different? Or is it just a matter of when using an actuall dataframe, the first line isn't needed? Thanks for the help BTW

Comment: You can fill the dataframe with the original data. Like `df = pd.DataFrame({'formula':['C18H36P1S1', 'C18H36P1S2', 'C18H36P1S3']})` (assuming you don't have a dataframe already)

Comment: @RustyDenton, What is the structure of your Dataframe. If you can give the first few lines, it will be easier to understand. This code will work with a column containing similar formula - as long as the hydrogens are followed by `H`

Comment: Or just use `df = ` your own dataframe. It'll work as long as you adjust the column name `formula` to match your dataframe.